# Laptop fan constantly running – Windows 10

Tags: laptop, memory, fan, lenovo-laptop, temperature

I just bought a Lenovo IdeaPad 310 15IKB a couple of days ago. The cooling fan never stops, running on high speed all the time, and is very loud, despite the fact that CPU usage is at 10% and the temperature is at most 32 °C.

I've tried a few solutions such as closing all background activities, updating the BIOS, and some others.

The device came with 4 GB of RAM and I have upgraded it to 8 GB, but the extra modules are different than the original ones. 
Is it possible that RAM is causing this problem?

I have tried to remove the extra memory, but the computer did not boot at all.

This computer has "anti-dust fan" feature.

I am running Windows 10 64-bit. My hardware is Intel Core i5 7200U, 8 GB RAM, Nvidia GeForce 920MX 2 GB memory and 1 TB HDD.

Comment: It sounds like the device is designed for the fan to run.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: I know it should run to cool down the cpu , but it is running on high speed even when I do nothing and the cpu is about 5%,the memory 17% and the disk is 0-1% .

Comment: my brother has an older version of lenovo ideapad with intel core i3 and it runs quietly even when he is playin far cry 4 and it lags a lot on his laptop , on my laptop it runs on fine but the fan starts to fly .

Comment: i5 is more powerful then the i3 it requires more active cooling

Answer (score 2):

"is it possible that the ram is causing this problem ??" **No**.

"anti-dust fan" feature" what the heck is that?

I would return it for a full refund, it should not be doing this and who cares why, you paid good money for a PC without defects.

Answer (score 0):

Try an Ubuntu liveCD to see if it's a software issue (like a missing driver) or a hardware issue (like a broken sensor).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party tools like [Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=5) to define a custom cooler curve:

[image]

Adjust it until the fan no longer runs all the time during idle. But check temperatures to avoid CPU damage!