# DELL Latitude 5480 with Intel Core i5 7th Gen laptop fan runs continously

Tags: battery, fan, dell-latitude, charger

Just to tell you some history. My laptop was recently upgraded to Windows 10. It was working fine with no issues. In just the past few days, it's making a lot of sound when the battery charger is plugged. The fan runs at full speed. It then calms down once the battery charger is removed. I have checked the event viewer and there is nothing mentioned related to hardware failure or other failures. Ran a diagnostics test on the laptop and it came back with no errors.

When the Mozilla Firefox browser is opened on the laptop, it makes such sound, but otherwise it works without any noise even when the charger is plugged in. I also found that the battery exhausts quickly when the charger is removed. The CPU utilization is always at its peak and reaches 100% when the browser is kept open. Is there someone could help me with this?

Comment: I like the comment mentioned here https://superuser.com/questions/1222250/laptop-fan-constantly-running-windows-10?rq=1 but I cannot wait, until I have a new one. Is there no fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check bios settings for an option like "**Fans Always on at AC**". Most of the time OEMs include that option because power consumption isn't a problem while you're charging your pc.

Comment: I did not have this problem when I received it from an OEM (Dell). This is happening only from last week. I had upgraded to Windows 10 probably 45 days before.

Comment: I had mentioned the same thing here https://www.dell.com/community/Latitude/DELL-Latitude-5480-with-Intel-Core-i5-7th-Gen-laptop-fan-runs/m-p/5667811#M223 and I have tried the fix. Let us see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I have included more information about the problem. Please check and let me know if you could be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that the fans run at full speed when the CPU is under heavy charge, like it seems to be the case when you run Firefox (you wrote the CPU is at 100% when the browser is opened).
And you reported there is no noise with other applications.
So I think the problem is related to your browser, and not to your entire computer. Try another browser, or try to uninstall all plugins from Firefox.